# The exact type of my 3d model

Tags: 3d, polyhedra, polygons, solid-geometry

> I have reconstructed vertical features (hole like objects lie on a
>   vertical face) lie on two connected faces. To understand the
>   situation, I say I have 2 walls with many windows and doors on each.
>   suppose, these two walls make rectangular corner. (I have inserted a
>   figure on my 3d model)

[image]

> *Now, I want to know the type of my 3d reconstruction because I am confused whether my model belongs to CSG, or B-REP or Polyhedral
>   or...*

*could you please clarify my model is belong to which type.* thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's B-rep, because you're defining an object by it's limits and non-manifold because your object has no thickness. It's also polyhedral for me because you're using only planar faces.